# В здании находящемся в безвозмездном пользовании или находящимся

Tags: орфография

в здании находящемся в безвозмездном пользовании или находящимся

Comment: "в здании, находящемся в безвозмездном пользовании" = "в здании, которое находится в безвозмездном пользовании".

Comment: "в здании, которое находится в безвозмездном пользовании" = "в здании, которым пользуются безвозмездно"

Answer (score 5):

В здании каком? находящемся -- предложный падеж.
И, кстати, после слов "в здании" нужна запятая.)

Answer (score 0):

Где-то слышала, что в таких случаях детям предлагают брать слово-помощник - любое прилагательное без шипящей. Например, умный: находящемся - умном = ОМ/ЕМ

Comment: Тогда надо брать слово с ударным окончанием: другом, голубом, чужом. Кстати, местоименное вопросительное прилагательное КАКОЙ  в нужной форме как раз и выполняет такую функцию. Каком? - окончание ОМ/ЕМ, после шипящих выбираем мягкий вариант ЕМ.